# Import commonjs default from ES6 module

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

I've got a commonjs module (`test.cjs`) that was generated by typescript compiler (with module: commonjs):

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = 1;
exports.foo = 2;
```

**Note**: This module is an external library.

Now I want to use the default export in an **es6 module** (`index.ts`) (with module: es6):

So I tried this:

```
import def, { foo } from "./test.cjs";
console.log(def, foo);
```

The output `{ default: 1, foo: 2 } 2`.

So non-default import is working fine, but default import expects `module.exports` to be the default.

Is there a way to have the es6 default import import `exports.default` instead of `exports` directly?

Comment: Use `module: commonjs` as well?

Comment: @Bergi I've got a mix of es6 and commonjs external libraries and I want to use es6 for my code. I can use def.default but unfortunately the type definition of the external libraries assume I'm using commonjs typescript setting (i.e. typescript will take care of importing exports.default). I can hack away by casting (`import testModule from "./test.cjs"; const def = (testModule as any).default as typeof testModule`) but am wondering if there's a cleaner way.

Comment: I don't think nodejs native modules support importing of transpiled-to-commonjs modules

Comment: A [custom loader](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_loaders) might be able to achieve the detection of `__esModule` commonjs modules